# Matthew Henry's Commentary on the Unfaithful Wife

Tags: gospel-of-luke, numbers, bible-commentary, matthew-henry

In [Matthew Henry's Complete Commentary](https://www.studylight.org/commentaries/mhm/numbers-5.html) on [Numbers 5:11-31](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Numbers%205%3A11-31&version=AKJV) (The Test of the Unfaithful Wife) there are several references to Luke 5:18-32 (Jesus Heals a Paralytic Man). How does the Old Testament test of an unfaithful wife relate to the New Testament healing of a paralytic man?

Answer (score 3):

It would appear that the two don't relate at all. I suspect that these verses in the resource that you've linked to are as a result of a transcription error as they don't appear at all in [this version](http://www.biblestudytools.com/commentaries/matthew-henry-complete/numbers/5.html) nor even in [the version that studylight claims for it's source](http://www.ccel.org/ccel/henry/mhc1.Num.vi.html).

Comment: This was my first impression, but I didn't have time to cross reference.

Comment: The entire page references Luke in inappropriate ways. Definitely something gone wrong there.I used their contact form to brig it to their attention.